# How to show JSON fields hierarchically in java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON object and want to show the fields hierarchically.

```
checkedTreeSelectionDialog.setInput(jsonObject);
```

Inside the `getchildren()` method of the `JsonContentProvider` class, I am parsing the json object

```
private void getChildrenForJson(final Object object) {

    final JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;

        for (final Object objct : jsonObject.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (jsonObject.get(objct) instanceof JSONArray) {
                    getArray(jsonObject.get(objct));
                } else {
                    if (jsonObject.get(objct) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        getChildrenForJson(jsonObject.get(objct)); 
                    }
                }
```

However, the returned fields are not coming hierarchically.

How can I get those fields hierarchically?

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortObject(o) {
    var sorted = {},
    key, a = [];

    for (key in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            a.push(key);
        }
    }

    a.sort();

    for (key = 0; key < a.length; key++) {
        sorted[a[key]] = o[a[key]];
    }
    return sorted;
}

private void getChildrenForJson(final Object object) {
    final JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;

            for (final Object objct : jsonObject.keySet()) {
                try {
                    if (jsonObject.get(objct) instanceof JSONArray) {

                      var q = getArray(jsonObject.get(objct));
                      var p = sortObject(q);
                      console.log(p);
                    } else {
                        if (jsonObject.get(objct) instanceof JSONObject) {
                     var q =getChildrenForJson(jsonObject.get(objct));
                     var p = sortObject(q);
                      console.log(p); 
                        }
                    }
```

This is what you were expecting , I hope !